"Where will She/Sara be tomorrow"? Or "Where will be She/Sara tomorrow"?
When we make "WH" questions, we can put the subject after the auxiliary verb, as in "Who will the President be?” or after the main verb “be,” as in "Who will be the President?”
My question is, if the subject is a pronoun or a name, should it go between "will" and “be” as in "Where will she/Sara be tomorrow?” or after "will be" as in "Where will be She/Sara tomorrow?”

Where will she/Sara be tomorrow is correct.

Technically, Who will the President be? is slightly ambiguous. It could (and is very much more likely to) mean the same thing as Who will be president? but it also permits the (odd) interpretation, The President—that single individual who keeps changing their identity—I wonder what identity they will choose to adopt. The first meaning could be replied to with answers like John Smith will be president, whereas satisfying the second meaning would require answers like Oh, the President so enjoys being John Smith, that’s what he will do.
This kind of ambiguity is not possible with the other wh- words.
And the pattern you’re looking for with regard to placement doesn’t depend on whether the subject is a pronoun, proper name, or any other substantive. It’s entirely to do with the particular word who. To see this, note that *Where will be the President? is no more acceptable than is *Where will be Sara? The reason that who does afford the two placements is that the resulting sentences have different syntax. Although the subject of Who will the President be? is the President, the subject of Who will be the president? is who. And this is reflected in the fact that the phrase the President, where the noun is capitalized, refers to the specific individual who occupies the role, whereas the phrase the president, without capitalization, refers to the position, not any specific individual.

Thanks but as you said "The pattern you’re looking for with regard to placement doesn’t depend on whether the subject is a pronoun, proper name, or any other substantive. It’s entirely to do with the particular word who" if that is the case can we say "Who will be She in future"? Or "Who will be Sara in future"?(as in what she will become professionally)

Who will be Sara? sounds as though someone were casting a play and wondering which actor would be assigned to play the role of the character named Sara.  It’s parallel to Who will be president? To convey the meaning that you intend requires Who will Sara be? The subject in this question is Sara, whereas in Who will be Sara? the subject is who, which is not what you seem to mean.

I don’t think you mean that someone is going to be Sara and you wish to know which someone that is.

Thank you. Now i understood it clearly.
